# How to use TelecomManager.getLine1Number()

Tags: android

I am using `TelecomManager` to get the phone number. But the `getLineNumber` is not working. The error is shown in the bottom image.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);


    final EditText number = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.phone);

    number.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TelecomManager tma = (TelecomManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            number.setText(tma.getLine1Number());
        }
    });


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;

}
```

[image]

Comment: The setText isn't the problem. You need a parameter in that method call

Answer (score 0):

As the error shows you, you need a PhoneAcountHandle to be passed to the function as an argument.

More on that can be found here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/PhoneAccountHandle.html